# emacsformacosx gdb no such file or directory

Tags: macos, emacs, gdb, osx-elcapitan

OS: Mac OS X 10.10 El Capitan

emacs: emacsforosx.com

gdb: GDB 7.12 from homebrew

Inside emacs->

```
M-x gdb
prompt: Run (like this): gdb -i=mi /bin/ls
prompt: No such file or directory.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find gdb path by using which gdb.

Then,

```
M-x gdb
prompt: Run (like this): /the/file/path/gdb -i=mi /bin/ls
```

As @MarkPlotnick said in the comment below:

For saving the file path for future reference,

```
(setq gdb-command-name "/path/to/your/gdb")
```

Comment: If you are interested in being able to shorten the absolute path to just `gdb`, then consider editing your question.  If you are happy with typing the full path, then accept your own answer in a couple of days after the mandatory waiting period.

Comment: Thanks @MarkPlotnick